# Getting Celebi in SSB Melee

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

For the record, yes I can google. Search results all say I need the following before I can see Celebi:

- All characters
- All stages
- All 51 event matches
- Beating Giga Bowser
- Beating Crazy Hand
- Sound Test
- Score Display
- Random stage select

(Some of these are redundant, and sometimes Giga Bowser and Crazy Hand are omitted in sources.)

I have done all of the above, checking the character screen for characters and the stage select screen for stages, as well as checking the message log to see that I've unlocked all characters and stages. I beat Giga Bowser after completing Adventure Mode on Normal in a speedy enough fashion, and beat Crazy Hand after completing Classic Mode on Normal also quick enough. The former gave me the Giga Bowser trophy but the latter didn't give me anything (so I don't have a Crazy Hand trophy, but sources say to get Celebi one must unlock "everything except trophies"). I did all of the event matches, got the sound test, score display, and random stage select.

In an attempt to see Celebi, I've had four computers playing Final Destination with the only item being the PokeBall set to Very High frequency. After observing and keeping track a bit, I estimate very conservatively that I've seen well over 800 PokeBalls opened and still no Celebi. Mathematically, as the chances of seeing Celebi in each PokeBall in a normal Vs. match are 1/251, the chances of *not* seeing Celebi in 800 PokeBalls is just over 4%. Either I've been pretty unlucky so far or I'm missing something - which is it?

P.S. I've never used action replay or any hacking tool, and I'm pretty sure I've never deleted my data (although it has been over 10 years since I've last played, according to the message log, lol).

P.P.S. Bonuses count in Vs matches right? So if I see Celebi in a Vs. match (even with all computers playing), it will count towards the Diskun trophy. If I do an unlimited time match and at some later point pause and reset, getting a No Contest screen, will all of the bonuses still count, and would seeing Celebi for the first time still count if it was done in that time period?

Comment: I always thought Celebi was one of those [goose chase rumors](http://www.ssbwiki.com/list_of_rumors#Unlocking_non-playable_characters) that weren't real, and only existed to make you do stupid hard things for no reward.

Comment: @Rapitor I've heard of Toad and Sonic/Tails and others in that way as characters but never Celebi as a Pokemon. In fact the wiki you linked to has an entry on Celebi consistent with what I've read elsewhere. Some other sources I'm reading now are saying Celebi has to be seen in $1$-player mode, or that it must be seen in Vs. Match with only human players. I'll experiment with this in a bit I guess.

Comment: So... I just went to training mode and threw a few PokeBalls. I didn't see Celebi, but then after I finished it said I've encountered Celebi for the first time. I have no idea WTF just happened. I'll probably delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it must be unlocked; it won't appear out of a Poké Ball until all playable characters and stages have been unlocked, the Sound Test has been unlocked, all Event Matches have been completed, and Score Display has been unlocked. Once that's done, the chance of Celebi appearing is 1/251

[***SOURCE***](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Celebi)

Comment: This just repeats back at me everything I already knew and even explicitly stated as background context, and does not address (or attempt to address) my question. Although I did end up bizarrely getting Celebi in training mode (even though I didn't actually see it), and I'm not entirely sure why. (See my comment above.) I suspect it's because my Vs. matches were always with computers only, and thus the Celebi I saw didn't count until I did something as a human player, which happened to be training mode. Who knows.

Comment: I am just trying to clarify everything that must be done before Celebi appears. It just so happens that the answer to your question is very straight forward with this information. Even though your question is long with a lot of context, the answer is quite short and simple. As long as the requirements are met, you have a percentage chance of seeing Celebi. Your theory about being unlucky should have been addressed in my answer - you can theoretically play forever and never see Celebi or Celebi can appear in every Pokeball. That's the bad thing about percentages in general.

Comment: That one must get everything before Celebi appears was already "clarified" in my question. According to you, I answered my own question. If the true answer here was "you are just unlucky, that's all," then *that's* what you should have said, instead of leading me on to believe you didn't read my question. (Note that before I saw Celebi in training mode, I did more vs. matches - all in all, the chances it would take someone as many pokeballs as it took me to see it is less than 0.1%, as an upper bound. I am not sure if luck is really the answer here.)

Answer (score 0):

Celebi is extremely hard and rare to see. You must fulfill requirements before you even have a chance to see it. The requirements are the following:
Unlock all characters. This can be done through a minimum of 1000 vs matches.
Unlock all stages. Yes, you must play 200 vs matches, get a Birdo or Pidgit trophy, clear classic mode with Mr. Game & Watch, clear All-Star mode, clear all events, clear all Target tests, get a distance of over 1300 in Home-run contest with Yoshi, and survive 15 minute melee.
Unlock special things. You must unlock all characters and stages and get a total of 5000 KOs.
Defeat the secret final bosses. You have to beat Crazy Hand and Giga Bowser in classic and adventure mode respectivley at least once.

After all that you have a 1/251 chance of it appearing in a poke ball. That's the same chance as Mew!